# How to show complete header label name in Select Columns header menu dialog(Column Chooser),when header column labels contain new line character?

Tags: eclipse, nattable, nebula

I've header menu configuration added in my nat table as follows,where I've included "Select Columns" menu as well:

```
// Popup menu

this.natTable.addConfiguration(new HeaderMenuConfiguration(this.natTable) {

@Override

protected PopupMenuBuilder createColumnHeaderMenu(NatTable natTable) {

  return super.createColumnHeaderMenu(natTable) .withColumnChooserMenuItem(); }

});

// Column chooser

DisplayColumnChooserCommandHandler columnChooserCommandHandler = new DisplayColumnChooserCommandHandler( bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer(), bodyLayer.getColumnHideShowLayer(), columnHeaderLayer.getColumnHeaderLayer(), columnHeaderLayer.getColumnHeaderDataLayer(), columnHeaderLayer.getColumnGroupHeaderLayer(), columnGroupModel);
```

//If header name consists of multiple words then I've used ("\n") as a separator between words in
//the header column name ,so that some space could be saved

//  In that case on opening "Select Columns" context menu dialog only first word of column is visible

Can it be fixed by replacing all "\n" and white space character by single white space(" ") character in
**In org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.columnChooser.gui.ColumnChooserDialog**
**//code to replace extra white spaces or new line character from column label with single space so that //header name is completely visible in populate tree method**
`treeItem.setText(columnEntry.getLabel())`;
In that case can fix be provided to replace extra space with single space in column header name or is there any other alternative to fix it?
[Image with header names having multiple words For eg:"Issue Date",if header name is dispalyed as "Issue\nDate",only Issue is visible in "Select Columns" context menu dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO7tz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you add the line breaks to save some space. They are not needed for any semantical reason. I would suggest to configure the `TextPainter` that renders the column header cell content to wrap automatically if not enough space is available. This could look like this for example:

```
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
    CellConfigAttributes.CELL_PAINTER,
    new BeveledBorderDecorator(new TextPainter(true, false, false, true)),
    DisplayMode.NORMAL,
    GridRegion.COLUMN_HEADER);
```

Comment: adding TextPainter was the first choice but in that case complete header name is not visible.

Comment: For example in case of "Issue Date" only "Issue..." is visible .That is why I added new line to see complete header name in the available space.Therefore requesting to remove extra space or new line character from treeItem.setText(columnEntry.getLabel()) in populateTree() of ColumnChooserDialog.So that complete header name is visible in Select columns dialog in header menu even on adding new line character in column header labels

Comment: Or is there any alternative way to make complete header name visible in header context menu Select Columns dialog when header labels have new line character?

Comment: If you register the TextPainter as shown in the snippet word wrapping row height calculation are enabled. So you should see the whole column header and no three dots. And no there is no way to handle new line characters in that dialog. But you can of course subclass and create your own dialog.

Comment: Thank you very much Dirk Fauth.Text  painter resolved the issue here.Text painter configuration was getting overwritten.Hence it was not effective earlier.After placing configuration correctly Text Painter worked in this case.Thank you ,this was helpful